# Debugging VBA only reads Compile Error: Expected Function or variable. I'm not sure what to do to fix this error

Tags: excel, vba, function, variables, compiler-errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE35n.png)I need help debugging this but everytime I debug the vba, it Compile Errors out:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yerur.png)

I need help finding the source of this problem and finding a solution please.

```
        With New frmForm
Sub Reset()
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = [Counta(HoursLog!A:A)] ' identifying the last row
        With frmForm
        .txtDATE.Value = ""
        .txtPROJECT.Value = ""
        .txtTASK.Value = ""
        .txtHOURS.Value = ""
        .LstHourLog.ColumnCount = 4
        .LstHourLog.ColumnHeads = True
        .LstHourLog.ColumnWidths = "30,30,30,30"
        If iRow > 1 Then
            .LstHourLog.RowSource = "HoursLog!A2:D" & iRow
        Else
            .LstHourLog.RowSource = "HoursLog!A2:D2"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
Sub Submit()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HoursLog")
    iRow = [Counta(HoursLog!A:A)] + 1
    With sh
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.txtDATE.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtPROJECT.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.txtTASK.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.txtHOURS.Value
    End With
End Sub
Sub Show_Form()
    frmForm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming `frmForm` is a UserForm, get rid of the `Sub frmForm...End Sub`, and then `With New frmForm` to create a new instance of the form.

Comment: @BigBen I replaced {Sub frmForm...End sub} with {With New frmForm} and it gives me a different error

Comment: You should get rid of `Sub frmForm...End Sub` entirely, and then change `with frmForm` in your *current* code snippet to `With New frmForm`.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of my entire code

Comment: Remove the `With New frmForm` at the beginning. Then within `Sub Reset`, change `With frmForm` to `With New frmForm` for starters.